# Generalization of formal grammars - production rules with more general functions?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, formal-grammars, natural-language-processing

Usually formal grammars have production rules in the format `N=tNt` where simple concatenation function is used for the expansion of the nonterminal. https://www.grammaticalframework.org/ has concrete grammars (e.g. FoodEng https://www.grammaticalframework.org/doc/tutorial/gf-tutorial.html#toc19 grammar) with more general production rules which involve special functions for handling inflextion, gender agreement and so on. Are there grammars (and corresponding deterministic finite automata) that can handle grammars whose production rules involve functions beyond simple concatenation?

Comment: Well, tree grammars aren't just "simple concatenations", but they define trees rather than strings, so they're probably not what you're looking for.